# How to split words further into letters in react hooks

Tags: javascript, css, react-hooks, react-memo

I have made a split of the Text. Now I want to split it further into a single letter/character. Further I want to extent the splitting process to a set of array which is inside the content.

Below is my react code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import content from "./content";
    
    // Splitting Texts
    const SplitText = React.memo(({ str }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {str.split(" ").map((item, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>{item}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
    
    // Main App
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>
            <SplitText str={"Lucie Bachman"} />
          </h1>
          <h2>
            <SplitText str={"Hey, this is my first post on StackOverflow!"} />
          </h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: what should be your expected result? Please add in the question itself...[Is this what you want](https://codesandbox.io/s/letterssldr-forked-x573x)

Comment: Yes, what did you do sir? actually, my requirement is to split not only a single string but an array of strings. I will be inserting an array like so <SplitText str={content.title} /> and <SplitText str={content.desc} /> inside the codesandbox

Comment: Please correct your data first because some of your elements in the `content` array contains an array `[]`.

Comment: yes sir.. corrected

Comment: Is this what you want [please go to this link and tell me](https://codesandbox.io/s/letterssldr-forked-c04ov?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, that's the result I wanted to continue further. So you just took off the gap inside the split and it gives me the split of individual letter ( -- str.split("").map ) Am I correct Sir?

Comment: Added the solution with explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `str.split(" ")` then you are saying that *split the string with separator as " "*. It will split the string where the space is there in the string.

But what you want is to split the string with each character, for that you have to split the string with `""` as

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
<div>
  {str.split("").map((item, index) => {
    return <div key={index}>{item}</div>;
  })}
</div>
```

**Resources**

1. [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same split API on string to get the letters

```
console.log("string".split('')); // ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```